# parse specific data from the list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

i am facing the problem which is to parse specific data from list. I have a list sth like :

```
response_list = [{
                "Name": "Brand",
                "Value": "Smart Planet",
                "Source": "ItemSpecific"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Color",
                "Value": "Yellow",
                "Source": "ItemSpecific"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Type",
                "Value": "Sandwich Maker",
                "Source": "ItemSpecific"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Power Source",
                "Value": "Electrical",
                "Source": "ItemSpecific"
            }]
```

From the list I should get the Brand name. Every time it will come in different position.How can i get it using list comprehension.Output will be like :

```
new_list =[{'Brand':'Smart Planet'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of `dict`s, you want to take only the *Name* and the *Value* field of this list.

You can do:

```
[{item["Name"]: item["Value"]} for item in response_list]
```

You get:

```
[{'Brand': 'Smart Planet'}, {'Color': 'Yellow'}, {'Type': 'Sandwich Maker'}, {'Power Source': 'Electrical'}]
```

Is it what you want?

**EDIT**

If you only want the brand name, you need to filter:

```
[{"Brand": item["Value"]} for item in response_list if item["Name"] == "Brand"]
```

Comment: yes somehow but i only need brand name.I mean the dict which is in first index